# Need help understanding 'Scrapy' error message

Tags: python, scrapy

I've recently gotten a task to update a website that utilizes a web scraping program, however, I am fairly new to it. The instructions given to me by the prior creator of the program were to run the main_executor.py and the website should run with no problem. However, that wasn't the case I am getting a bunch of error messages that I'm unsure of. I was hoping someone with more experience could look at it and explain to me the problem.

Error message:

```
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

= RESTART: C:\Users\khoih\OneDrive\Desktop\RA Files\CyberSite\research\research\main_executor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\khoih\OneDrive\Desktop\RA Files\CyberSite\research\research\main_executor.py", line 4, in <module>
    setting = get_project_settings()
  File "C:\Users\khoih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "C:\Users\khoih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 287, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "C:\Users\khoih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'research'
```

Any help would be aprrcieated and I can provide the code if needed.

The main_executor.py code:

```py
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

setting = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(setting)

for spider_name in process.spiders.list():
    print ("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
    process.crawl(spider_name,query="dvh") #query dvh is custom argument used in your scrapy

process.start()
```

Comment: Please provide main_executor.py, code is always better than no code

Comment: What are your project settings?  It looks like it is requesting a module that you haven't provided.

Comment: Please [edit] your post so that it doesn't contain images of error messages. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question